"Unsafe assignment of an error typed value" typescript-eslint error
At the time of asking this question, "Unsafe assignment of an error typed value" returned zero Google results, so it seems worth an SO question.
The error is produced by linting the following TypeScript code
const map = {
  0.1: 'bar',
};

const x = Math.random();
// "ESLint: Unsafe assignment of an error typed value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment)"
// https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment/
const s: string = map[x];
console.log(s);

eslintrc consists of this rule:
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "error"
  }
}

Here's a typescript-eslint playground showing the error.
What causes the linter to output this error?

Unsafe assignment of an error typed value. 8:7 - 8:25

What exactly is the "error" typed value it refers to?
One solution was to explicitly type map as const map: Record<number, string> but I'd like to understand that "error" typed value, because s could at most be assigned undefined.

The reason this returns no results is because this exact error message comes from a release on 10th June 2024, when they started differentiating "error" and "any".

For me, this error was something that showed up in VSCode, but went away once I restarted the IDE. ‍♂️

TL;DR: this error indicates that you are trying to assign a value of type any to a variable, which although technically legal in TS, might not be what you intended to do, or even worse, you might not even be aware you're trying to do. So ESLint throws an error to notify you of this any assignment, just in case you didn't know it was there.
The type of const map is inferred from its definition - since you defined map as an object with only one key pre-defined (the 0.1: "bar" one), but with a possibility that new keys may be added, TS is able to infer the type of only this one key (which is string); other potential keys are inferred to have the type any by default.
When the compiler/transpiler processes your code, it does more or less the following deduction:

const map = { 0.1: 'bar' };

map is 100% sure to have a key 0.1 of type string; all other keys, if any, can be whatever really, i.e. are of type any.
I cannot be 100% sure that new fields haven't been added to map between its declaration and its usage.


const x = Math.random();

I don't know for sure what value variable x holds, but I know it is of type number.


const s: string = map[x];

The dev is trying to access map[x], but since I don't know the exact value x, I can only assume that any type of value could be accessed with it (ergo map[x] has the type of any).
I know 100% that const s is expected to be of type string.
assigning any to a variable of type string should be OK I guess.



This is where ESLint kicks in, which sees TS's deduction and it, so to say, "declares":
I am not certain that the developer noticed that they are trying to assign an any to a string. Therefore, I'm going to throw an error to notify him of this fact and let him deal with it explicitly.
If after this error, you change the code to remove the use of any (by specifying the type more closely), the linter did its job. And even if you just disabling the linter off at that point, it still did its job, as it just wanted to make you aware of the potential issue (and you dealt with it).
So the correct course of action would be both to set the map type to const map: Record<number, string>, and to disable the linter at the problematic line. Though I'd argue the former is more preferable in the vast majority of cases.

It absolutely is ok

Thank you for your answer Nesh. In the meantime I've encountered this error in other situations, so I'm trying to get a better understanding before accepting.

Feel free to edit the original post with some of those other situations, maybe we can help

I think Nesh's explanation is right, but the 'error' part of it is what's annoying.. I found the same issue, for me I imported a type, and used that type, whenever that type was used I would get this error... the type itself had an issue, it was generated in a folder like /myTypes/myTypes/ instead of /myTypes/ so relative references from those types were not proper, which weirdly enough I got no warning or error during the tsc step (which is done by a CLI utility, I have no direct handling of it).
So, yes, for me it was an 'any' thing being assigned to something properly typed, but the reason it was an 'any' was b/c the definition of the type had an issue.
Hope it helps someone.
